# boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension - how to drop first index and leave out the rest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im having an issue with display the features selected using lasso algro

```
X = df.drop(['Target'], axis=1)
y = df.Target

# We use the base estimator LassoCV
clf = LassoCV(cv=3)

# Set a minimum threshold of 0.70
sfm = SelectFromModel(clf, threshold=0.70)
sfm.fit(X, y)
n_features = sfm.transform(X).shape[1]

# Extracting the index of important features
feature_idx = sfm.get_support()
```

when I want to see the selected features it throws the eror

```
df.columns[feature_idx]
```

error

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 1075 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1074
```

I know df.columns include the target Y, is there how to remove the first index and keep the rest to avoid the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the size of your boolean array (e.g., `[False, True, True]`) doesn't correspond to the size of the array you're trying to index. If you just

```
df.drop(['Target'], axis=1).columns[feature_idx]
```

The order will be the maintained, because the feature selector was fit on `df.drop(['Target'], axis=1)`.